# find a string in every line of a file then replace another string on the same line using bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, arch-linux

here is my script :

```
#! /bin/bash

# C-band Edit
dqt='"'
str5="polarization=${dqt}2${dqt}"
for x in {3600..4200} do;
    sed -i "/$str5.*$x/s/$x/$((x-600))/" satellites.xml
done
```

all i want to do is to replace number x with x-600 in between 3600 and 4200
on all lines that have str5 in satellites.xml but the script above gives me syntax error

Comment: Change `for x in {3600..4200} do;` to `for x in {3600..4200} ; do` maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just occurred to me that you didn't mean the literal string `x-600`, you meant "subtract 600 from every value found between 3600 and 4200".  In that case, use perl, not sed:

```
echo "$str5. foo bar 3200 3964 4155 4200 4255" |
  perl -p -e "if (/$str5/) {s/3[6789]\d\d|4[01]\d\d|4200/$&-600/eg}"
polarization="2". foo bar 3200 3364 3555 3600 4255
```

This uses perl's `/e` regex modifier to cause the right-hand-side (`$&-600`) to be **evaluated as a perl expression**.  `$&` is a perl variable that contains the value of the match, so `$&-600` means subtract 600 from that value.

I'll leave my original answer below in case that was what you actually wanted.  Also because it has useful explanations that are still somewhat relevant to the perl answer above.

Like sed, perl has a `-i` option for in-place editing so you can apply this directly to your satellites.xml file.   See `man perlrun` for details.

```
perl -i -p -e "if (/$str5/) {s/3[6789]\d\d|4[01]\d\d|4200/$&-600/eg}" satellites.xml
```

Also worth noting: You probably should use an XML parser when you're working with XML files.  Fortunately, perl has several to choose from, e.g. [XML::Parser](https://metacpan.org/dist/XML-Parser) or the collection [libxml-perl](https://metacpan.org/release/libxml-perl).

---

I don't have a sample of your actual input, so I made one up that will demonstrate what will get changed, and what won't:

```
str5='polarization="2"'

echo "$str5. foo bar 3500 3964 4155 4200 4255" | 
  sed -e "/$str5/ {s/3[6-9][0-9][0-9]/3-600/g; s/4[01][0-9][0-9]/4-600/g; s/4200/4-600/g}"
polarization="2". foo bar 3500 3-600 4-600 4-600 4255
```

Roughly translated to English, that's "if the current line contains $str5 (`polarization="2"`), then apply these three `s///` operations to it".

Notes:

- There is no need to loop from 3600..4200.  This will make all the changes in **one** run of `sed`, not 600 runs.
- You wanted values from 3600-4200 to be changed.  That means you need 3 search and replace operations:

  - one for 3600-3999
  - one for 4000-4199
  - one for exactly 4200
- Alternatively, this could be done with two `s///` operations, by combining the last two into one:

  ```
    sed -e "/$str5/ { s/3[6-9][0-9][0-9]/3-600/g; s/4[01][0-9][0-9]\|4200/4-600/g }"
  ```
- There are probably many other ways to optimise the regexes, but the more you do that, the harder they'll be to read and modify in future.
- `3964`, `4155`, and `4200` were changed.  `3500` and `4255` were not, they fall outside of the desired range.
- `[0-9]` won't work as you might expect in **some** locales (where there are other characters in that range).  I don't know exactly which locales, but I've seen it mentioned often enough to know that `[0-9]` can't be entirely relied upon.  If this affects you, you can use `[[:digit:]]` instead of `[0-9]`, or use `perl -p` instead of `sed` (so you can use `\d` instead of `[0-9]`).  Same applies to the range `[6-9]`, use `[6789]` instead.
- Finally, be very careful about what you put in the `$str5` variable.  Because it is being interpolated into a `sed` command, it will be very easy to break the sed script (e.g. if `$str5` contained a `/`, it would break the `/$str5/` match). sed does not know that its script came partially from a shell variable, all it sees is the script it has been given to run.

  Also, the entire string will be **interpreted by sed as a regular expression** - that means that regex metacharacters will not be interpreted as literal characters unless they are escaped with a `\`.  e.g. `.` will be interpreted as "any character" rather than a literal dot unless it is escaped as `\.`

Comment: i want the whole number to be subtracted by 600 i.e 3600 will be 3000 and 3964 will replaced by 3364 and so on ..

Comment: yes, already done that.  sed can't do it, you have to use something more capable, like perl.

Comment: thanks alot the perl command works exactly like i want

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt is correct in principle, you just missed to close the list before the `do` with a semicolon, as frabjous pointed out:

```
for x in {3600..4200}; do
```

But please note that this will make you edit the file 601 times "in place", actually creating and deleting hundereds of new files each time you execute that.

To avoid that you can

1. Teach `sed` some basic understanding of numbers to do it in one pass, which it fun, but not really useful
2. Use a tool that can calculate numbers like `python`, `perl` or `awk`
3. Reduce it to only seven actual replacements you can feed into `sed`:

```
    #! /bin/bash
    # C-band Edit
    dqt='"'
    str5="polarization=${dqt}2${dqt}"
    sed -Ei "/$str5$x/{"$(for x in {36..41}; do echo -n "s/$x([0-9]{2})/$((x-6))\\1/;"; done)";s/4200/3600/;}" satellites.xml
```

The substitution will produce the `sed` script

```
s/36([0-9]{2})/30\1/;s/37([0-9]{2})/31\1/;s/38([0-9]{2})/32\1/;s/39([0-9]{2})/33\1/;s/40([0-9]{2})/34\1/;s/41([0-9]{2})/35\1/;s/4200/3600/
```